# WCF Method not found after signing an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, gac

I have a 3 projects in a solution like such:

- WCF Service: Hosts a couple of methods
- Class Library: Acts as a gateway to the WCF service by returning an instance of its Soap client
- WPF Application: Consumes the service methods via the referenced class library

Everything was working perfectly...the application was accessing an instance of the soap client through the library and consuming the methods accordingly.

Now I signed my assemblies and everything still compiles and when I add new methods and update the service reference in the library, the new methods come up in the application...but when running the application and try to use a method, a `MissingMethodException` is thrown:

> Method not found:
>   'MusicData.Entities.User
>   DBAccess_Gateway.DBInteraction_Service.DBInteractionGatewayClient.User_Login(System.String,
>   System.String)'.

This is the line its failing at:

```
 var user = WSGateway.MR_WebService.User_Login(username.Text, crypto.Encrypt(passphrase.Password));
```

I think it has something to do with the assemblies (now in the gac because they are signed?) being signed...but why arent the methods are not being found?  Are the signed assemblies not being updated correctly now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update the service references in your class library, make sure you are creating a new version of the assembly and registering this new version in the GAC, then make sure your WPF app is referencing this new version.